# Apps script Regex: SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

[image]

Based on https://www.plivo.com/blog/Send-templatized-SMS-from-a-Google-spreadsheet-using-Plivo-SMS-API/ I have the following code:

```
function createMessage(){
  data = {
    "SOURCE" : "+1234567890",
    "DESTINATION" : "+2345678901",
    "FIRST_NAME" : "Jane",
    "LAST_NAME" : "Doe",
    "COUPON" : "DUMMY20",
    "STORE" : "PLIVO",
    "DISCOUNT" : "20",
  }

  template_data = "Hi   , your coupon code for discount of % purchase at  is "
  Logger.log(data);

  for (var key in data) {
    Logger.log(key);

    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      template_data = template_data.replace(new RegExp('+key+', 'gi'),data[key]); // error here
    }
  }
  Logger.log(template_data);
  return template_data;
}
```

When I run `createMessage` I get :

```
SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier +. (line 57, file "Code")
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why is an error message in a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading '+' in your regular expression is what causes the problem. '+' is the quantifier that specifies how many patterns should be matched (in this case, one or more). So when you have the quantifier without the pattern, it's like matching one or more of 'nothing'.

Comment: So how do you fix this? I'm not a regex expert

Comment: @user61629 start by explaining in detail to yourself what you want to with the RegExp you create, then contrast that with what you think `new RegExp('+key+', 'gi')` is doing (and what you think `new RegExp('\+' + key + '\+', 'gi')` is doing).

Comment: Thanks it turned out that there is an error in the tutorial . I should read: template_data = template_data.replace(new RegExp(key, 'gi'),data[key]);